# In the morning VS on the morning

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct? (Maybe both are correct.)

> He passed away **on** the morning of March 5.

**Or**

> He passed away **in** the morning of March 5.

Comment: It's so strange to see, that no-one provided specific rules or references after several years of the question being open, and everything is based on "IMO"... weird. There are [specific rules](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/88100/33182) in English for this case, when talk about a **specific** morning, afternoon, or when we describe **the part of the day**.

Answer (score 22):

In your sentences, *on* is the correct preposition and *in* is the incorrect one. This is a bit tricky.

"He passed away *on* March 5" is correct. "He passed away *in* the morning" is also correct. However, in your sentence, "the morning" is a characteristic possessed by March 5, "March 5's morning," as it were. (Note that we would never say "March 5's morning"; I'm just using it to help illustrate that we're using a form of the possessive here). So, "He passed away *on* the morning of March 5" is correct.

If we turn things around a bit it may help to make things a bit more clear: since "he passed away *on* March 5 *in* the morning" is correct, it follows that "he passed away *in* the morning *on* March 5" is also correct.

A couple of additional observations:

> He passed away some time *in* the three hours prior to Joe's arrival.
> He passed away *at* 10 am *on* March 5.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense and you got a reason as well. I agree with you.

Comment: Actually it is "the morning" that is being modified by the "March 5," with the use of "of." Another example of this, The Mountain of Honeylily, you can say The Honeylily Mountain, with the "Honeylily" modifying the "Mountain." I'm not really sure, please reply if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Xyenz That sounds right to me too.

Comment: @Xyenz Five years later (!), I come to a different conclusion, which I believe is the correct one. The actual relationship is not an adjective/noun one but a possessive one: "the morning of March 5" is the same as "March 5's morning," i.e. the morning belonging to March 5. (We would never say "March 5's morning"; I'm just using it to illustrate.) I've edited my post to reflect my changed thinking.

Answer (score 8):

You say "in the morning/in the afternoon/in the evening". These indications of time stand alone and the concept is in + period of time.

It is another thing for "on the morning of the first of May". Here the concept of date/on this day prevails and has become the accepted expression.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems none of the answers explain why is it like that, what are the rules, what's the usage, and no-one provided references. I will elaborate and will post my investigation, as I did here at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/320818/168453).

Just to cut the long story short, for this specific case: "**on**" is the correct preposition and "**in**" is the incorrect one.

"*The morning of*" functions as an adjectival phrase clarifying the specific time and date "**on** *March 5*". "On" is used because it belongs to the date here, specific part of the day.

The normal language constructions would be:

- **on** + *date* (with the year or without it) or *day of the week*
- **in** + morning, afternoon, evening (*in* the morning, *in* the evening)

But, when we talk about a specific morning, afternoon, or when we describe the part of the day it should be used with **on**:

- **on** the morning of **[date]**,

You can't say "*I will see you **on** the morning*" - it's incorrect.

here's the reference for more examples: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time

> In or on?
>
> We use **in** with morning, afternoon, evening and night, but we use **on** when we talk about a specific morning, afternoon, etc., or when we describe the part of the day.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes, especially the link to the Cambridge Dict page can be very helpful for English learners.

Comment: There are no real rules for prepositions. Prepositions are highly idiomatic. Which preposition to use where is simply something that has to be learned by rote. There aren't any rules that aren't broken somewhere. Why, for example, we say "on Tuesday" instead of "at Tuesday" isn't a matter of any rule; it's a matter of habit. Either one is reasonable, but only the first one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> He passed away in the morning on March 5 - is correct.

We use *in* for mornings, months and years, and *on* for dates. We use *on* for the days (Monday, Tuesday...etc). We use *at* for time (At 7 o'clock in the morning on Sunday in March...for example).

Further reading [here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your help and I agree with you. I understand that but I just read on Yahoo so just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @user62015 You are welcome. Don't consider everything that you find on the Internet an authentic source!

Comment: @user62015 Oh, looking at your profile, I remember you now! You're the one who finds flaws in Yahoo! :) No offense please! haha

Comment: Thanks, haha but I am not after Yahoo. It is a good source to check out news and when I read something, which I have not read yet so I ask generally. You and other people have been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

**On + "noun which is a time label stands for a long time( usually one day / one month )"**

on Saturday : Are you free on Saturday to come for a dinner?
on Monday

**In + "the" +"noun which is a time label stands for a short time( usually some point of the day)"**

in the morning: he is the type who would wake up in the morning.

---

**Why do you see "On the morning"?**

this is mostly comes from " on Monday morning ". but "On the morning" is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

These both sound weird to me. I would reword to:

*He passed away in the morning **on** March 5*

or

*He passed away **during** the morning of March 5*

Answer (score -1):

In the second, minute, hour, morning, afternoon, evening, night, day, week, month, year, decade, century and millenium using "in" means within or during. On the second, minute, hour, morning, afternoon, evening, night, day and week using "on" means a specific moment in time. For a specific month, year, decade, century or millennium, on is dropped and only the definite article is needed. THE month, year, decade, century or millennium is indicated as a specific time period and on becomes redundant.