# in the morning of, on the morning of

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference, prepositional-phrases

> The baby was born in the morning of June 3.

> The baby was born on the morning of June 3.

Is there any difference between the two sentences in their meanings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the morning VS on the morning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18763/in-the-morning-vs-on-the-morning)

Answer (score 1):

"In" seems preferable to me (native UK English speaker).

"In" implies some instant in the time period between midnight starting June 3 and midday June 3. Sometime within that 12 hour period the baby was born.

"On" is what you would use for a date. Despite the fact that a day is 24 hours in length, when used as a date in a calendar, the date is treated as a single point in time.

Hence you could say:

> "the baby was born *on* June 3, *in* the morning"

and it would all sound more natural than "on the morning of..."

Comment: As _another_ native UK English-speaker I think I disagree. This question was answered [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18763/in-the-morning-vs-on-the-morning).